# Plotting graph in GNU PLOT using C#

Tags: c#, gnuplot

I have a dat file `insert.dat`

The contents are as follows:

```
1000    0.002322044 0.00291182
5000    0.000103257 0.000458963
10000   2.50E-05    0.000172019
20000   6.18E-06    6.03E-05
40000   2.51E-06    2.65E-05
60000   1.65E-06    1.71E-05
80000   1.21E-06    1.23E-05
100000  1.01E-06    9.97E-06
```

When I open the `gnuplot.exe` and type plot `insert.dat` with lines, I get a proper output but when I write a C# code as follows:

```
private  void GNUPlot()
{
    string pgm = @"E:\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe";

    Process extPro = new Process();
    extPro.StartInfo.FileName = pgm;
    extPro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    extPro.StartInfo.Standardization = true;
    extPro.Start();

    StreamWriter gnupStWr = extPro.StandardInput;
    gnupStWr.WriteLine("plot \"insert.dat\" with lines ");
    gnupStWr.Flush();
}
```

**I get the following warning:**

```
warning: Skipping unreadable file "insert.dat"
```

When I replace

```
gnupStWr.WriteLine("plot \"insert.dat\" with lines ");
```

with

```
gnupStWr.WriteLine("plot sin(x) ");
```

I get the required `Sin(x)` graph output.

`insert.dat` is in the current directory of `gnuplot`. I want `insert.dat` file data to be plotted.

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes around `'insert.dat'` instead?

Comment: write a plot.p script and exec gnuplot plot.p

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Ya I tried 'insert.dat' too. It is still not working. It is giving the same warning

Comment: @Exceptyon Pls explain how to write..

Comment: @guddi: I mean, if you execute "gnuplot script.p" from the command line, gnuplot will execute all the lines in script.p. So, I'd say write the script file from c# and simply invoke gnuplot with first argument the script filename...

Comment: @Exceptyon yes thank u :) I got it now

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that *gnuplot* cannot find the requested file. The working directory of the process is not set to the *gnuplot* directory, but probably to the directory of the application that is calling *gnuplot*.

**EDIT** Try to add either of the following lines to your code somewhere before the `extPro.Start()` command:

```
extPro.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"E:\gnuplot\bin";
```

or

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"E:\gnuplot\bin";
```

If this is not working, it might be because your application does not have read access to that directory. Try placing your *insert.dat* file in a directory that with certainty can be accessed by any client application.

BTW, I also do not recognize the `Standardization` property that you are using? That line should rather read:

```
extPro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

Comment: @guddi I have updated my answer with some additional information. In particular, are you sure that your application has read access to the *gnuplot bin* folder? The error message you are receiving is typical for the case when the file cannot be found (or accessed), the `plot` command by itself seems to be OK.

Comment: Thank You :) I got it. Now it is working. I wrote the script in file.gp and gave this file as an argument  [link] (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/50df756e-3a57-4554-ada7-734eccb14b33)